# How to sort alphabetically but respecting the length (shorter lines first)

Tags: linux, sorting, command

I want to sort the lines in file alphabetically, but respecting the line length (shorter first)

Example:

```
a
b
aa
bbb
zzzz
ccccc
```

using the sort command i get:

```
a
aa
b
bbb
ccccc
zzzz
```

How can I get the first output?

Comment: First part (sorting on length): `awk 'BEGIN { maxlen=0 } {len=length($0); a[len,NR]=$0; if (len > maxlen) maxlen=len  } END { for (row=1; row <= maxlen; ++row) for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (a[row,i]) print a[row,i]; }'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `cat your_file`; do echo ${#i}$'\t'${i}; done | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

1. insert the length of each line with a cut delimiter(\t) to each line;
2. sort by numeric sort (-n);
3. remove useless strings

Comment: Nice, but will fail when the input file has spaces. You can fix this with `while read -r i ; do .... done < your_file`.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment I suggested an approach that would turn into something ugly like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { maxlen=0 }
   {len=length($0); a[len,NR]=$0; if (len > maxlen) maxlen=len }
   END {
          for (row=1; row <= maxlen; ++row) {
            for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
               if (a[row,i]) {
                  ax[i]=a[row,i];
               }
            }
            asort(ax)
            for (s in ax)
               print ax[s]
            delete ax
          }
       }' input
```

I was put back on track after reading the smart solution of @Bo. His code is a lot faster and cleaner than my solution above (tested after rewriting it into `while read -r i; do echo ${#i}$'\t'${i}; done < input | sort -n | cut -f 2-`). The same trick can be done in awk, and with the right approach awk works well:

```
awk '
   { len=sprintf ("%20s",length($0)); gsub(/ /,0,str); a[NR]=len "_" $0; }
   END {
            asort(a)
            for (s=1;s<=NR;s++)
               print substr(a[s],22)
       }' input
```

Answer (score -2):

Javascript (arr is the array):

arr.sort().sort((a,b)=>(a.length > b.length));

Explain:

The first part: arr.sort() will return an alphabetically sorted array.

The second pard will sort again by element's length.

(a,b) => (a.length > b.length) can also be written as:

```
function(a, b){return a.length > b.length;}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations with the answer.

Comment: What language is this? Not much use if the user doesn't know how to execute it, eh?

Comment: It is JavaScript and can be tested on a browser console.

Comment: @g.sui the question is tagged "linux", which implies that the author wanted something executable via shell script.  While it is possible to execute JS in the shell (e.g. via `node`) you'd need additional code to read and write the data along with this.